# Preventing FOUT when using locally stored fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have developed an application that is meant to be used offline. It is deployed with it's own, custom tailored, web server and uses default browser to connect to it.

Since it's offline, I also have fonts stored in filesystem, that are loaded with `@font-face`. Apparently, due to many styles and character sets, they take up some time before the browser load them.

I'm testing it with Chrome (latest), and the *flash of unstyled text* (FOUT) is really annoying.

How could I reduce the FOUT when working in local context?

Answer (score 0):

How about hidding the entire html, or all of the text, before your css file is loaded?

At the top of your head you'll include inline styles likeso:

```
<head>
    <style>html{visibility: hidden}</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/default/style.css"/>
</head>
```

At the bottom of style.css, or after the @font-face declarations, you'll make the html visible again:

```
html {visibility: visible}
```